# What is the proper way of creating deserialization C# classes from XML data?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm on a project where C# deserialization classes appear to have been generated based on XML files, rather than directly from system XSD's.

Can someone please confirm: An XSD created from this single XML file could be missing metadata as some properties may be either null or missing, depending on how the XML file is generated.

From what I understand, the proper way to do this is to generate classes directly from system XSD's rather than from XML files, and identify some issues when generating from XML's?

Comment: Yes, in principle XSD is the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Optional elements or fields that are missing from the sample XML file will not appear in the generated XSD file and thus not in the deserialization classes. This is also the same for a single item appearing in the XML where a list of items was expected. Even if you have a full XML file it might be missing constraints, etc. you would have in your XSD.

My suggestion is to always start from the XSD. Then create a test XML file to test against it.

Comment: Another fun one: a potentially repeated element that was only present once in the sample xml; or string fields that only had values like "123" in the sample xml, but which can actually hold things like "hello"